# SPSS- assigning mulitple numeric codes to one variable

Tags: syntax, spss

I am trying to assign multiple codes to existing variables.  I am using the syntax below, but it will only assign the first code entered for that `hosp.id.number`.

Syntax example:

```
 Do if (hosp.id.number=9037) or (hosp.id.number=1058) or      (hosp.id.number=11256).
 Compute role_EM_communication=10.
 Else if (hosp.id.number=9037. 
 Compute role_EM_communication=11.
 End if.
 Execute.
```

`hosp.id.number` needs to be coded 10 and 11, but it will only code it at 10.  Anyway to rephrase so that SPSS will accept 2 or more codes for a variable such as `hosp.id.number`?

Comment: Firstly, the line `Else if (hosp.id.number=9037.` is missing a closing parenthesis.

Secondly, your question does not make sense. Or moreover, the logic to allow dual assignments to a single variable (`role_EM_communication`) makes no sense. And finally, the `ELSE IF` would never be executed because the same condition would be true in the `DO IF` before it.

Comment: The closing parentheses was deleted by accident when I copy/pasted syntax.  The syntax did work to some degree.  It is assigning all the appropriate codes, only it will only assign one code per hosp id- when I need it to assign 1-3 codes per id depending on data (as needed).  Is it executing all the else if's that do not have a hosp id yet assigned?  Do you have any suggestions on how to do this with syntax?  I need to assign some hosp id's multiple codes in the data set and have those multiple codes be counted in the frequency table.

Answer (score 0):

Your `role_EM_communication` variable is a single variable, but from what you are saying, I think you need it to be a **set** (for the same record, it could take on more than just one code). So you need to create **n** variables named `role_EM_communication_1` to `role_EM_communication_n`, where n is the maximum number of codes you estimate will be possible for one record.

For your example, it would translate like this:

create the 2 variables:

```
vector role_EM_communication_ (2, f2.0).
```

do the first recode:

```
if any(hosp.id.number,9037,1058,11256) role_EM_communication_1=10.
```

very important - execute the recode

```
exe.
```

check if the first variable has data, and populate the second variable if true:

```
if miss(role_EM_communication_1) and any(hosp.id.number,9037) role_EM_communication_1=11.
if ~miss(role_EM_communication_1) and any(hosp.id.number,9037) role_EM_communication_2=11.
exe.
```